# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in a context.js file when using a custom hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stack-size

I am getting the error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and it is pointing at the "useStore" custom hook.

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

//custom hook , useStore
const useStore = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);

  return {
    user,
    cartCount,
    login: () => setUser("Jack"),
    logout: () => setUser(""),
    addToCart: () => setCartCount(cartCount + 1),
  };
};

const StoreContext = createContext(null);

export const StoreContextProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <StoreContextProvider value={useStore()}>{children}</StoreContextProvider>
);

export const useLogin = () => useContext(StoreContext).login;
export const useLogout = () => useContext(StoreContext).logout;
export const useAddToCart = () => useContext(StoreContext).addToCart;
export const useUser = () => useContext(StoreContext).user;
export const useCartCount = () => useContext(StoreContext).cartCount;
```

I tried to search for the reason and I knew it is due to recursive function. However, I can't seem to understand my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that it's caused by this context?

Comment: Yes, it is were the error message refer to this file. However, I am still trying to figure it out cause I am new to learning about Context.

Comment: @Konrad This is GitHub Source code which is differentiating between context, context selector and zustand. The issue appears in context and context-selector files. https://github.com/jherr/mastering-context/tree/main/pages/ecommerce